# There is a very unusual output I got to see in Javascript loops while working with array

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, loops

When I iterate using `for` loop the output shows 7 undefined indexes but for the same in `forEach` loop it does not show that. And If I assign "undefined" to any of the indexes, It shows in `foreach` loop.
Why is that?
This is the code snippet:

```js
let x = [1, 2, 3];
x[10] = 55; // explicitly passing value to 10th index of array

for (let i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  console.log(x[i]);
}

x.forEach((item) => {
  console.log(item);
});
```

Output:

for loop output:

```
1
2
3
7 <undefined>
55
```

forEach loop output:

```
1
2
3
55
```

Comment: `forEach` method will iterate through an array object and will skip all array elements which don't exist at all

Comment: @ChrisG no, it's not true. It will skip empty element, but will iterate over `null` and `undefined`

Comment: [`forEach(callbackFn)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach): _"`callbackFn` is invoked only for array indexes which have assigned values. It is **not invoked for empty slots** in [sparse arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Indexed_collections#sparse_arrays)."_

Comment: corrected my comment, it actually skips elements which don't exist at all

Comment: References: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for  Now if you run  `console.log(Object.keys(x));`  before and after the `x[10] = 55;` you can see how the new key was added - keys are non-negative integers. `[
  "0",
  "1",
  "2",
  "10"
]` so as you see the array `.forEach` uses the keys but the `for` is not part of the array prototype and does not know about the keys.

Comment: `push(23)` if done after the `x[10]` would add a new key (11) with value 23 since it mutates the array